# Upload image with laravel and image intervention to local path

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, image, local-storage

I am trying to get images to upload to a public folder to be displayed with the items they belong to. All the other information goes into the database properly, but the images path won't upload or display.

Here is the form snippet

```
 {!! Form::open(['route' => 'rentals.store', 'files' => true]) !!}
  {{ form::label('image', 'Upload Image', ['class' => 'label']) }}
  { form::file('image') }}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here is the laravel/Image Intervention Code

```
 $rental = new Rental;

  $rental->title = $request->title;
  $rental->name = $request->name;
  $rental->description = $request->description;
   if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
       $image = $request->file('image');
       $filename = time() . '.' . $image>getClientOriginalExtension();
       $location = public_path('img/' . $filename);
       Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);

        $post->image = $filename;
     }               

     $rental->save();
```

Comment: Have you seen the generated HTML by the Form:open? is it generating the enctype attrbute correctly?

Comment: Also, i think you are saving the wrong value in the wrong column: $post->image = $filename, shouldn't it be $rental->image = $location?

Comment: @erubeil my understanding is that with form helpers you add 'files' => true and that takes care of it. When I view the code it looks right. Not sure that I follow completely on the second part...

Comment: Ignore the first comment, havent used the files => true option, always used enctype directly, but yours should be right. The second part, let me write it as an answer to use the correct markup

Answer (score 1):

This line of code.

```
$post->image = $filename;
```

1. Where is the `$post` being loaded? i think this should be `$rental`
2. You are saving the filename, just the filename, like in `someFile.jpg`, but you should, either save the full route to your file, or completing the route by yourself while trying to display it. You already calculate this route on `$location`
3. If saving in the post is what is correct for you, then you'll need to actually save it. you'll be missing `$post->save()` or `$post->update()`

Comment: oh my god I was not even paying attention to that part. I kept thinking that post was meaning post this. By changing that to rental it saves it correctly. Thank you.